# indexOf Not Working?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2, actionscript-1

I made this so only messages starting with '/msg' or '/logout' will submit.

But, users can still send messages! Is something wrong with my code?

```
if ((msg.indexOf("/msg") != 0) && (msg.indexOf("/logout") != 0))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: I even tried replacing '!=' with '!==' and it still did not work.

Comment: I think your logic is good.. try `trace`ing the value of `msg` to see if it checks out.

Comment: Please don't put tags in your title.  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`indexOf`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#indexOf%28%29) will return -1 if the `String` is not found otherwise it will return the index found which is >= 0

So your test have to be:

```
if ((msg.indexOf("/msg") < 0) && (msg.indexOf("/logout") < 0))
{
 return;
}
```

or

```
if ((msg.indexOf("/msg") == -1) && (msg.indexOf("/logout") == -1))
{
 return;
}
```

Comment: The question states that only messages __starting__ with "/msg" and "/logout" are acceptable (`indexOf` returns 0). Your solution will accept these strings _anywhere_ in `msg`...

Comment: P.S. -- this works just like the OP's code, but accepts MORE messages and is thus incorrect. I believe the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Turns out my code did work. The issue was in code I neglected to show you but I fixed it. Thanks for the help anyway and yeah glad you caught it too. :) In 8 hours do I accept an answer or answer it myself or what?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my code did work. The issue was in code I neglected to show you but I fixed it.

Thanks for the help anyway. :)